# How do I delete all the disks in a deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to delete all the Persistent Volume Claims attached to a customized deployment. At first, I delete the deployment itself that deletes all the pods but the disks aren't deleted.

I know the command to delete pvcs but that involves fetching all of them using a command[1] and then manually copying-pasting[2] the ones that belong to the deployment set.

If I want to do this programmatically, which API of Kubernetes Python client or the cli command do I use?

I am using GKE.

I tried reading the [Python client documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md) but could not deduce how to do this task.

[1]`kubectl --namespace=<my_namespace> --context=<my_cluster> get pvc`

[2]`kubectl --namespace=<my_namespace> --context=<cluster_name> delete pvc data-avirals-july19-1-devel-0 data-avirals-july19-1-devel-1`

Answer (score 2):

There might be some shorter way, however this one would filter all the pvc associated with the deployment name `MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME`. Other `pvc`(not associated with the same deployment) will not be touched.

```
for volume in $(kubectl get deployments MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.volumes[*].name}');
    do
      kubectl get pv $volume -o jsonpath='{.spec.claimRef.name}{"\n"}' ;
      # kubectl delete pvc "$(kubectl get pv $volume -o jsonpath='{.spec.claimRef.name}{"\n"}')"
done
```

Note:

1. **uncomment** the command `kubectl delete` to really delete the pvc. Its commented to protect users from accidently deleting.
2. `bash` is required to make this loop work.

Explanation:
Following command would list down the volumes used by a deployment called `MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME`

```
kubectl get deployments MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.volumes[*].name}'
```

Now,we will loop over these volumes, to find what is the `claim` used by these volumes. This is done my checking `claimRef` section. This is done by:

```
kubectl get pv $volume -o jsonpath='{.spec.claimRef.name}{"\n"}'
```

Comment: I think `nginx` should be removed from your command given you have already mentioned `MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME`. Also, I am not getting any output from this.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to delete `nginx`.  fixed that now.

Comment: what does `kubectl get deployments MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.volumes[*].name}'` return ? if this is returning empty then the `for loop` would do nothing .....also it implies that there is no volume configured for the depoyment.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all pvc at once with the following command:

```
kubectl --namespace=<my_namespace> delete pvc --all
```

The PVs should be deleted after that but it might take some time. Also, be very careful with this command and make sure you are deleting what you intend to.

Comment: No, that won't work because it will delete all the PVCs in the *namespace*, my aim is to delete all in the *deployment*.